# Bootstrap positioning like in airbnb photo gallery

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to positioning my blocks using bootstrap 4 like in a airbnb gallery?

I'm tried do it like here, but I've got it with spaces on sides

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: red;">
    <a class="lightbox" href="./images/bg.jpg">
      <img src="./images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"style="background-color: green;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a class="lightbox" href="./images/bg.jpg">
        <img src="./images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a class="lightbox" href="./images/bg.jpg">
        <img src="./images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a class="lightbox" href="./images/bg.jpg">
        <img src="./images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a class="lightbox" href="./images/bg.jpg">
        <img src="./images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how I can do it without those spaces?

Comment: Add div with .row into the second .col-lg-6

Comment: @PavelTřupek Thank you man!

Answer (score 0):

Cols should always be parented by .row. Add div with .row into the second .col-lg-6:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: red;">
    <a class="lightbox" href="./images/bg.jpg">
      <img src="./images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"style="background-color: green;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="lightbox" href="./images/bg.jpg">
          <img src="./images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="lightbox" href="./images/bg.jpg">
          <img src="./images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="lightbox" href="./images/bg.jpg">
          <img src="./images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="lightbox" href="./images/bg.jpg">
          <img src="./images/coast.jpg" alt="Coast">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read over the [grid system in Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

In general each ROW should have COLs that add up to 12 for each size breakpoint, or use the new bootstrap -auto to adjust for width for a dynamic width column.  There are more complicated options you can do with flexbox and otherwise, but sticking to the above advice should get you pretty close

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-9">2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">5</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">7</div>
  <div class="col-md-auto">8 - this one is long and will take up space</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">9</div>
</div>
```

[Try the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f67sqhw/)